# In Ruby on Rails is there a better way than using eval() to accses this jsonb dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, eval, jsonb

I've got some jsonb in a database and I want to write to an attribute dynamically, I know the path to the attribute but it could be any depth and any attribute name.

I know the path to the attribute, however the only way I've found of writing this dynamiaclly is with `eval()`.

```
eval("self.some_json_column['an_array'][10]['a_different_array'][5]['color'] = 'blue'")
self.save
```

So I know the depth and the array index, but it could be any depth or index. I can build the string and pass it into `eval()`

However I know that `eval()` is a last case scenario and was wonderign if it's possible to build the path and write (in this case that color json attribute) dynamically without using `eval()`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce your way through the `Hash` that is returned by `self.some_json_column`

```
*path, target = ['an_array',10,'a_different_array',5,'color']
node = path.reduce(self.some_json_colum, &:[])
node[target] = 'blue' if node
```

This has no error handling if any part of the path is incorrect

You could also look into `dig` depending on ruby version like so

```
node = self.some_json_column.dig(*path)
node[target] = 'blue' if node
```

This will return `nil` if any part of the path does not match

Example:

```
h = {
  'an_array' => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
    {'a_different_array' => [1,2,3,4,5, {'color' => 'orange'}]}
  ]
}

*path,target  = ['an_array',10,'a_different_array',5,'color']

h.dig(*path)[target] = 'blue'

h
#=> {"an_array"=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
#     {"a_different_array"=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
#       {"color"=>"blue"}
#     ]}
#   ]}
```

Comment: It would be nice to have `plant` as a companion to `dig`.

Comment: We could beautify it a bit: `*path, index = depth_chart` and then `h.dig(*path)[index] = 'blue'`

Comment: @tadman it certainly would however I am uncertain of the return value of a failed planting I guess we could go with `nil` and a counterpart `plant!` that would raise but since planting is almost a setter maybe the planted value should be returned?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk as you say so it shall be

Comment: @engineersmnky Yeah, `plant!` could potentially make any intermediate structures as required. I've had to do that quite often when creating abstract JSON documents, for example.